# Selenium's send_keys does not work for a specific field

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a text field that I cannot write to. I can click on it just fine and it does put the cursor there, but using send_keys doesn't do anything.

What could be causing this ?

Edit :
I've just had the idea to test it in pure javascript (field.value = "0"), and it does type but the input get deleted after a second. So there's some javascript linked to that field that erases the result if it doesn't come from the keyboard. Is there a way of simulating keyboard events from javascript ?

Edit : The question maked as duplicate mentions using javascript to edit the field's value, which I have done as described above and it hasn't worked.